# script to insert filename of folder into table in oracle

Tags: database, oracle

```
create table file_details (file_id number(10), filename varchar2(50))
```

I have 1 folder on widows machine and its path is `C:\New Folder` there are 50 text files in it.

I want to insert all the file name into `oracle table` using `PL/SQL`.

Comment: we can do it through frontend but through backend I don't get any idea. Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DBMS_BACKUP_RESTORE package or create a [Java stored procedure that lists the contents of an operating system directory](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3A%3A%3A%3AP11_QUESTION_ID:439619916584) and call that from PL/SQL